# paracol and lettrine - problems with small paragraphs

Tags: lettrine, paracol

If I use `lettrine` inside a `paracol` environment and `parindent` is set to `0mm`, the following problem arises if the paragraph on both sides is just one line:

There is no indentation in the next line and the text is overlapping with the text of lettrine.

How can I detect the paragraphs that consists of just one line and automatically add the needed indentation for the next paragraph? (Lettrine is used about 2000 times in documents with different page width, manual adjustment is not an option.)

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{paracol}
    \usepackage{lettrine}
    
    \setlength{\columnsep}{3mm}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    \switchcolumn[0]
    
    \lettrine{1}
    Not much text
    
    \switchcolumn
    
    \lettrine{1}
    And again
    
    \switchcolumn*
    
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    
    \switchcolumn
    
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    
    \switchcolumn*
    
    \lettrine{2}
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    Some text
    
    \switchcolumn
    
    \lettrine{2}
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    Some other text
    
    \switchcolumn*
    
    \end{paracol}
    
    \end{document}
```

As @John Kormylo pointed out, this is not a problem of `paracol`.

My solution, based on his answer, is as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newlength{\CLFL}% Custom length for lettrine
\newlength{\IFLL}% Indentation for lettrine left
\newlength{\IFLR}% Indentation for lettrine right
\setlength{\IFLL}{0pt}
\setlength{\IFLR}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lettrineLeft}[2]% #1=letter, #2=paragraph
{\bgroup
    \setbox0=\vbox{\lettrine{#1}{}{\global\CLFL=\dimexpr \L@height-\L@lraise-\ht\strutbox} #2}%
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr \CLFL-\ht0-\dp0}
    \ifdim\@tempdima> -10pt
    \setbox0=\hbox{\lettrine{#1}{}{\global\IFLL=\dimexpr\L@Nindent-0.5\fontdimen2\font\space}}
    \fi
    \egroup
    \lettrine{#1}{} #2}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lettrineRight}[2]% #1=letter, #2=paragraph
{\bgroup
    \setbox0=\vbox{\lettrine{#1}{}{\global\CLFL=\dimexpr \L@height-\L@lraise-\ht\strutbox} #2}%
    \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr \CLFL-\ht0-\dp0}
    \ifdim\IFLL> 0pt
    \ifdim\@tempdima> -10pt
    \setbox0=\hbox{\lettrine{#1}{}{\global\IFLR=\dimexpr\L@Nindent-0.5\fontdimen2\font\space}}
    \fi
    \else
    \global\setlength{\IFLL}{0pt}
    \fi
    \egroup
    \lettrine{#1}{} #2}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\indentLeft}{\ifdim\IFLL> 0pt \hskip\IFLL\global\setlength{\IFLL}{0pt}\fi}
\newcommand{\indentRight}{\ifdim\IFLR> 0pt \hskip\IFLR\global\setlength{\IFLR}{0pt}\fi}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
        \switchcolumn[0]
        
        \lettrineLeft{100}{Not much text here.}
        
        \switchcolumn
        
        \lettrineRight{1}{NAnd again}
        
        \switchcolumn*
        
        \indentLeft Some text..a
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        
        \switchcolumn
        
        \indentRight Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        
        \switchcolumn*
        
        \lettrineLeft{2}{Some text
            Some text
            Some text
            Some text
            Some text
            Some text
            Some text
            Some text
            Some text}
        
        \switchcolumn
        
        \lettrineRight{2}{Some other text
            Some other text
            Some other text
            Some other text
            Some other text
            Some other text
            Some other text}
        
        \switchcolumn*
        
        \indentLeft
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        Some text
        
        \switchcolumn
        
        \indentRight
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        Some other text
        
        \switchcolumn*
        
    \end{paracol}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure that paracol matters in this.  The problem is detecting the end of a paragraph without running into \end{document} or some such.

Comment: You're right, this has nothing to do with `paracol`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution requites you to add the entire paragraph as an argument. The computation is based of fooling around with different length registers until it looked right.

One should always end a paragraph with `\strut` before `\switchcolumn*` or other commands which break `\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newlength{\Ltht}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\latrine}[3]% #1=letter, #2=wirdm #3=rest of paragraogh
{\bgroup
  \setbox0=\vbox{\lettrine{#1}{#2}{\global\Ltht=\dimexpr \L@height-\L@lraise-\ht\strutbox} #3\strut}%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\dimexpr \Ltht-\ht0-\dp0}
  \ifdim\@tempdima> 0pt
    \unvbox0\vskip\@tempdima
  \else
    \unvbox0
  \fi
\egroup}
\makeatother  

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn[0]

\latrine{1}{}{Not much text}

\switchcolumn

\latrine{1}{}{And again}

\switchcolumn*

Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text\strut

\switchcolumn

Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text\strut

\switchcolumn*

\latrine{2}{}{Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text
Some text}

\switchcolumn

\latrine{2}{}{Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text
Some other text}

\switchcolumn*

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This did not exactly answer my question, but pointed me into the right direction. Therefore I accept your answer.